# React File naming convention to jsx

Tags: node.js, npm, reactjs

I am new to react. Initially I started using `create-react-app`. File names were `index.js` by default. Then I renamed the file to `index.jsx`.

When I try to start the application using `npm start` I am getting the below error.

```
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.js
  Searched in: D:\WorkSpace\React\chat\src

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Applns\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Applns\\nodejs\\node_modules\\
npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! chat@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the chat@0.1.0 start script 'react-scripts start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the chat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
```

How to resolve this. How can I make node to take the jsx file.

Answer (score 1):

rename index.js instead of index.jsx it will work properply as I m using create-eact-app

Comment: ReactJS components needs to be in .jsx files right? as a standard?

Answer (score 0):

A file with that extension is being imported by another file. The extension has changed so the lookup will fail. Also, React doesn't need the files have `.jsx` to work. So just by simply switching the file extension back should work. I've never used `create-react-app` but if you wan't to make it work with `.jsx` you'll most likely have to do some additional configuration on top of it's default configuration. I'd check out the docs for this.

Comment: ReactJS components needs to be in .jsx files right? as a standard?

Comment: It's not a requirement, but some people prefer it.  Others make the argument that the `jsx` transformation is only one of the transformations that occur on the file to make it valid javascript that can run in a browser, and so it doesn't make sense to name the file differently because of it.  I personally don't have any strong feelings either way, but usually go with just `.js` files so I don't need to change it later if some `jsx` syntax needs to be added.

Answer (score 0):

As @KeithA mentioned - you need additional configuration. In you webpack.config.js in the `resolve` object:

```
resolve: {
 ///...some other configurations will go here ...

  extensions: [ "", ".js", ".jsx" ]
},
```